# What's the easiest way to get a link directly to an answer?

Tags: support

I can get the link to a **question** by hovering the cursor over its title. What's the smart way to get a direct link to one of the **answers**?  The only way I know is to go to the user's page and hunt for it there. So I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All posts (questions and answers) have a "share" link beneath them, in the same area where the "edit" link is. This brings up a pop-up with a short URL that links directly to the question or answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You might want to use it for questions too, since the link in the title of the question is the long form, which has a portion of the title embedded.

Comment: This is what I've been using in my posts.  For what it's worth, you can also get links to *comments*.  Place your mouse over the comment's time and date, right click (or your browser's equivalent), and choose "Copy Link Location" or similar item from the pop-up menu.

Comment: I wish there was a magic text-generating button that would construct a `[title](url)` string and put it in my copy/paste buffer. It is so time-consuming to make those by hand, but I think people would use them all the time, even in comments. I think that the addition of the title (or eye-candy) would increase the frequency that people will go ahead and click through, increasing awareness.

Comment: Also, using the share link allows you to gain points towards badges, whereas using the URL doesn't.

Comment: @uhoh: If you simply do `[url]` with the url being a Space.SE question or answer, it automatically displays it as the question title.  Not sure if it works with questions *across different* SE sites, though.  Does not seem to work for comments.

Comment: Test: [https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1273/58] [https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1274/58] [https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-link-directly-to-an-answer/1274?noredirect=1#comment4844_1274] [https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31824/6] [https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/31825/6] [https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/31767/why-is-the-equinoxes-only-2-days-and-not-more#comment57796_31767]

Comment: @DrSheldon Didn't work in the comments at all. Was that what you were talking about?

Comment: @DrSheldon Didn't work in an answer for me either.

Comment: Just posted a sample below.  I was wrong about the square brackets, just the bare URL.  I do it all the time!  I only know of it working *from* a question or answer (not a comment), *to* a question or answer (not a comment).  I'm not sure if the different behavior regarding comments is intentional, or should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @DrSheldon Oh yeah, I do a bare URL in questions and answers too. I wish that worked in the comments.

Comment: @DrSheldon Bare URL only works for links to questions though.

Comment: @called2voyage: Ah, correct you are.  I don't link to answers nearly as much as I do questions, and apparently when I do, I tend to write something like `In [this answer](...)`.  Whereas I do *a lot* of `Related:` followed by a bare question URL.  I should have noticed the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a test of `https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1273/58`

[What's the easiest way to get a link directly to an answer?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1273/58)

Testing `https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1274/58`

https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1274/58

Answer (score 1):

It does work, even with long titles. However, this is *display feature* (appearance only) and is subject to change. It's not the same as button that creats a real text string of the form: `[title](url)` which you can copy/paste anywhere without depending on the page to regenerate the appearance of the title.

Also, <s>I'm not sure what happens to the title generation/appearance</s> if the original post is deleted the displayed text reverts back to the bare url (per comments below, thanks folks!).

Testing `https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1128/12102`

[Slightly nonstandard questions from new users frequently getting the silent, drive-by insta-close votes, can something be done?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1128/12102)

Testing `https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1112/12102`

[Is voting to close a question for "primarily opinion-based answers" while answering with fact exercising faulty logic, or even gamesmanship?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1112/12102)

---

However it doesn't seem to work for questions from another site:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22022/did-the-space-shuttle-boat-tail-used-in-the-transport-configuration-save-fuel

so [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36319/12102) I've done it manually again.  Here's how it looked before my edit (after I re-pasted the url just to make sure):

> [image]

Comment: If the original post is deleted, the title won't be resolved at all and showing the bare URL instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. I would guess as much as well, but how do you know? What makes you say that?

Comment: @uhoh I tested it--he's right.

Comment: @called2voyage but it doesn't seem to work from another SE site? (see edit)